# Elastic Search Phonetic issue with NEST in Dotnet

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-analyzers, elasticsearch-phonetic

I am new in Elastic search and i want to use it for Phonetic search so I have added plugin NEST in dotnet using nougat package and tried to create index with phonetic but getting following error.

ServerError = {ServerError: 400Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "Unknown filter type [phonetic] for [my_metaphone]"}

```
var result = client.CreateIndex("indexName", i => i
            .Settings(s => s
            .Analysis(a => a
                .Analyzers(x => x.Custom("my_analyzer", ca => ca.Filters("standard", "lowercase", "my_metaphone")))
                .TokenFilters(x => x.Phonetic("my_metaphone", pf => pf.Encoder(PhoneticEncoder.DoubleMetaphone)))
                ))
                .Mappings(m => m
                    .Map<CityModel>(mm => mm
                    .AutoMap()
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.Name)
                            .Analyzer("my_analyzer")
                            .SearchAnalyzer("my_analyzer")
                            )
                            )
                            )
                            )
                );
```

Can any one help me to create index with phonetic configuration in dotnet?
Thanks in Advance

EDIT :

I can able to create index with below json request.

```html
<pre>
PUT /indexname
    {  
     "settings": {
      "index": {
       "number_of_shards" : 4,
       "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
         "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["standard","lowercase","my_metaphone"]
          }
           },
        "filter": {
         "my_metaphone": {
          "type": "phonetic",
          "encoder": "metaphone",
          "replace": false
             }
           }
          }
        }
        },
          "mappings":{  
             "crm3":{  
                "properties":{  
                   "@timestamp":{  
                      "type":"date"
                   },
                   "@version":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "AccountCategory":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "AccountNo":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "AccountStatus":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "ActivationDate":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "AnniversaryDate":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "BirthDate":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "CityName":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "ContactNumbers":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "EmailIDs":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "FirstName":{  
                      "type":"text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"text"
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "Gender":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "IMSINumber":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "IsBlackListed":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "LastName":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "MiddleName":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "OrganizationName":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "Segment":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "SubscriberID":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "SubscriberNo":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "SubscriberTypeName":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "host":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "message":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "path":{  
                      "type":"text",
                      "fields":{  
                         "keyword":{  
                            "type":"keyword",
                            "ignore_above":256
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
    }
    </pre>
```

Using C# linq scenario is not working, Can any one guide for the same?

Comment: Did you install [phonetic analysis plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.2/analysis-phonetic.html#analysis-phonetic-install)?

Comment: Yes Rob, I had already installed that plugin but still not working.

Comment: What version of elasticsearch/NEST are you using?

Comment: I am using Elasticsearch version 6.2.1 and for NEST version 6.0.1.

Comment: Could you check if the plugin was loaded up by elasticsearch by calling `http://localhost:9200/_nodes`?

Comment: I have tested with url which you suggested but I am getting empty array in plugins.

Comment: Json request of creating index from Kibana console is working fine with phonetic analysis plugins but not sure about C# syntax or dotnet NEST connector misbehave.

Comment: Are you connecting to the same instance of elasticsearch as kibana does?

Comment: Issue is solved after restarted elasticsearch instance. i made mistake that after installed phonetic plugin, I was forget to restart elasticsearch instance. Now able to fine plugin using this url (http://localhost:9200/_nodes),
Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved once restart elasticsearch instance after installed phonetic plugin. And you can find using this url (localhost:9200/_nodes) as Rob suggested.